# How to treat missing data for forecast package in r

Tags: r, time-series, yahoo-finance, financial, forecast

I want to forecast closing prices of indices I download from Yahoo finance using `quantmod` package. The result is that the data don't include weekends, bank holidays and whenever markets were not open. I use all available techniques from `forecast` package. However, I have a problem with frequency. I believe I can solve the weekend problem by setting frequency to 5 (for weekly data), but it doesn't always work due to bank holidays.
How do you suggest I solve this problem?
I know it is not a problem for `prophet` and Machine learning techniques.
To get data from yahoo finance use the following code:

```
library(quantmod)
my.df <- getSymbols(Symbols = "^FTSE", auto.assign = FALSE)
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you may find suggestions how to manipulate `xts` object here: https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/r-xts-cheat-sheet.

Comment: Thanks! I just need to know what should I transform my data to so that forecast works best